Conversion Issue From Object to Xml In Pact Test
I am working on contract testing using PACT framework of a springboot application with a rest controller. It's a GET call and the method is annotated with
@GetMapping(value = "/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
this method calls service method i.e.
MyObject myObject = service.lookupMessage(<string_param>);
and returns
ResponseEntity.ok(myObject)
From my provider class setup I am mocking this call
@MockBean
private MyService mockedService;

var responseXml = Files.readString(Path.of("src/test/resources/mock/full_message.xml"));
MyObject myObj = TestXmlUtils.unmarshalContractSource(responseXml);
RootClass rootClass = new RootClass(myObj.getData1(), new Data2());
when(mockedService.lookupPain001Messages(anyString())).thenReturn(rootClass);

In the consumer test I am expecting the response to be string xml because in the real scenario springboot is converting the object response to xml. First, I run the consumer and it runs successfully. When I am running provider it fails returning status code 200 which is correct but the body is not matching
The problem is that this object to xml conversion is not happening because we are not in spring context. Pact bypass the context and is unable to make this conversion due to which controller returns Object, which is correct, but the consumer is expecting String
Please let me know how to make this work.
Edit: I am using this version of Pact
        <dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.consumer</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit5</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.14</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.provider</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit5</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.14</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


Use SpringRunner with ContextConfiguration and MockBean
